# Shorthand for calling Singleton Instance in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was currently using a singleton to store some common variables as a state using singleton so that their memory were allocated just once. for eg :

```
public class PlayerRuntimeVariables
{
    private PlayerRuntimeVariables()
    {
    }
    private static PlayerRuntimeVariables instance;
    
    
    public static PlayerRuntimeVariables Singleton
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("PlayerRuntimeVariables Singleton Instance is null, creating instance");
                instance = new PlayerRuntimeVariables();
            }
            Debug.Log("PlayerRuntimeVariables Singleton returning instance");
            return instance;
        }
    }
    public float movementSpeed{ get; set; }
}
```

But in doing so, I have to write

```
PlayerRuntimeVariables.Singleton.movementSpeed
```

in order to get that variable **(movementSpeed)** which is lenghty and time consuming as there are many variables used in furthur logic and storing them again in some variable didnt seem to be a good solution.

Is there a shorthand approach for accessing that variable.

 For eg in Scala

```
object SomePlayer{
   val a = 10;
}
```

We can access that SomePlayer.a using imports anywhere in the code:

```
import SomePlayer._ 

......
int hereWasNeeded = a;
```

Do we have that kind of flexibility with c#.

 I looked for imports/using wrt c# but couldnt found as such .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a much better way than to store the singleton in another variable:

```
var prv = PlayerRuntimeVariables.Singleton;
// ...
prv.movementSpeed; // Btw, public fields should be named in PascalCasing in C#
prv.SomeOtherField;
```

You can use the `using` statement to create an alias for the type, but that still leaves you with the `Singleton` part:

```
using Prv = Some.Namespace.PlayerRuntimeVariables;
// ...
Prv.Singleton.movementSpeed;
```

Comment: yeah, seems this is the only way ..also Thanks for the casing and using info as well :)

Comment: For that , you need go a bit of extra mile and create a class. 
public Class PlayerRuntimeVariablesSingletonAccessor 
{
    public static   movementSpeed  
 {
  get
  {
    return PlayerRuntimeVariables.Singleton.movementSpeed;
  }            
 }         

}
PlayerRuntimeVariablesSingletonAccessor prv;
prv.movementSpeed;